# sql server get value between spaces in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need help in getting the value in between spaces in one column. For the requirement below, I would need the value after the first space.

I have a column with multiple rows:

**Original_Column**

```
Microsoft SQL Server
Oracle DB Server
Delete From Table Name
SELECT as123 987
```

The expected output is

**Expected_Output**

```
SQL
DB
From 
as123
```

Comment: Please share the query you have tried thus far. You will need SubString and CharIndex functions to get the result.

Comment: Find the first space, find the next space (starting character after initial space), Substring from those two index points. (CHARINDEX)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick for this type of problem is to use `parsename()`.  I think the following does what you want, assuming there are no periods in the names:

```
select parsename(replace(val, ' ', '.'), 2)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41014) is an example.

EDIT:

Sgeddes is correct.  If you consistently want the second name and can have three or four parts, then `reverse()` can be used:

```
select reverse(parsename(replace(reverse(val), ' ', '.'), 2))
```

(It seems that one of the values does have four parts; I originally read it as "Delete From TableName".)

Comment: +1, I like this, but I think it should be used with `reverse`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/703ce/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `Substring, Charindex and Left string function` to get the value.

```
select left(substring(Col,charindex(' ',Col)+1,len(Col)),charindex(' ',substring(Col,charindex(' ',Col)+1,len(Col))))
```